# Hudson Deploy error on Tomcat 7

Tags: hudson-plugins, maven-cargo

I am deploying a WAR file with Hudson 2.1.2 Post Maven Build which fails with this error message. I have the Hudson deploy plugin installed

> Deploying
>   C:\Users\Admin\workspace_astra\astra-maven\target\astra-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
>   to container Tomcat 7.x Remote   The property cargo.tomcat.manager.url
>   has been deprecated, please use cargo.remote.uri instead. ERROR:
>   Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to
>   exception org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to
>   redeploy
>   [C:\Users\Dieter\workspace_astra\astra-maven\target\astra-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:191)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:62)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:92)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
>     at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)    at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:45)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:584)
>     at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:159)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:553)
>     at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1391)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/manager/list     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:507)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:644)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:657)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:172)
>     ... 17 more java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://localhost:8080/manager/list    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:507)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:644)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:657)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:172)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:62)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:92)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
>     at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)    at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:75)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:45)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:584)
>     at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:159)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:553)
>     at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1391)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)

Where do I change this cargo.tomcat.manager.url to cargo.remote.uri within my hudson environment, as this is what is doing the deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. There is a bug in the deploy plugin for tomcat 7, so Dominique Righetto kindly rewrote it for everyone an placed it online at Google Docs here https://docs.google.com/#folders/0B7SAopRfWOagNjk5MjBjYTMtODEyYy00ZGRiLTgxZWQtODk1ZDdmN2M4Nzc2.

They speak about it here on the Hudson Wiki

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Deploy+Plugin

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was confused with the problem. There was not manager app running in my tomcat. In your tomcat, inside the webapps folder you should have a folder called manager(this is the one to see manager app). If this is not available "http://localhost:8080/manager/list" this link does not work.

There are two ways to solve this. 
1) install new tomcat and make sure this has manager folder.
2) copy the manager folder from some other place, if you have zipped version of tomcat.

once manager folder is copied, restart the server. Before doing restart, you may need to have manager-* roles enabled to the user that you are trying to access the manager app.